# Verification that spreadsheet is protected

Tags: ruby, excel

does anybody know how to validate that an excel spreadsheet is password protected? I just need to know wether the file is protected or not. If helpful the password used for the protection is available.

Thanks in advance!

**Update 1**:
The file itself is readable and only some parts are write-protected. That's why the general runtime exception for accessing a read/write protected file does not work.

**Update 2**:
Sample file: http://cl.ly/3B3l1a2A3t3t

Comment: which protection are you referring to-worksheet, or workbook structure, or password to open?

Comment: Workbook or worksheet would be both working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open the spreadsheet and trap the run time error...

```
require 'spreadsheet'
begin
  book = Spreadsheet.open './mysheet.xls'
  sheet1 = book.worksheet 0
  sheet1.each do |row|
    puts row
  end
rescue RuntimeError => e
  puts "password protected!" if e.to_s.include? "Unknown Codepage"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Steve. In my case I only have write protection for some parts of the file. Reading in general works without any runtime exceptions. I updated the description above.

Comment: Ok, can you use the same prinicple?  Read the spreadsheet, then do, say, a dummy update and see if you get an exception?

Comment: I tried that but no runtime exception occurs. Additionally the new file is written without sheet protection.